# Draw 2 lines in Highcharts. JSON malformed?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm trying to draw 2 lines on a graph with Highcharts . The PHP server -side file is:

```
require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); 
$sesionUser = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
$sesionIdGrupo = $_GET['idGrupo'];
$sesionFechaActual = $_GET['fechaActual'];
$sesionFechaActualArreglo = date_format(new DateTime($sesionFechaActual),"Y-m-d");

$query_RecordsetTabla2 = "SELECT idDispositivo FROM dispositivos WHERE idUsuario = (SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE userName = '$sesionUser') AND idGrupo = '$sesionIdGrupo'";
$RecordsetTabla2 = mysql_query($query_RecordsetTabla2, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_RecordsetTabla2 = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetTabla2); 

while ($row_RecordsetTabla2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla2))
{
    $idDispositivo = $row_RecordsetTabla2['idDispositivo']; 

    $query_RecordsetTabla3 = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE idUsuario = (SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE userName = '$sesionUser') AND idDispositivo = '$idDispositivo' AND fecha = '$sesionFechaActualArreglo'";
    $RecordsetTabla3 = mysql_query($query_RecordsetTabla3, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalRows_RecordsetTabla3 = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetTabla3);
    if ($totalRows_RecordsetTabla3 != 0) {  ///para ver si tienen resultados la consulta
    unset($items);      

        while ($row_RecordsetTabla3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla3))
        {
        $fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla3['fecha'];
            $hora = $row_RecordsetTabla3['hora'];
            $estado = $row_RecordsetTabla3['estado']; 
        $arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y-m-d");
            $arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H:i");
        $arregloHora2 = strtotime($arregloHora) * 1000;
        $arr = array($arregloHora2, floatval($estado));
        $items[]  =  $arr;
        }
        $items2  = array ( 'data' => $items , 'name' => $idDispositivo );
        echo json_encode($items2);
    }/////del IF
}
mysql_free_result($RecordsetTabla);
mysql_free_result($RecordsetTabla2);
mysql_free_result($RecordsetTabla3);
?>
```

... and returns JSON string :

```
{"data":[[1398416400000,1],[1398419100000,1]],"name":"2"}{"data":[[1398418200000,1],[1398419100000,1],[1398420000000,0]],"name":"16"}
```

And the answer file goto javascrpt client side :

```
$.get("mostrarStatsGrupo.php", datos, function(data){
var titulo = 'Red '+ memoria.nombreGrupoSeleccionado +' a día '+ memoria.fechaActual
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'divStatsGrupo',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: titulo
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,        
    },
    xAxis: {

        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats : {
            hour: '%H:%M',
            labels: {
                style: {
                    width: '200px','min-width': '100px'
                },
            useHTML : true
            }
        }   
    },
    yAxis: {
        categories: [ 'APAGADO', 'ACTIVO', 'ALARMA'],   
        title: {
            text: 'ESTADO'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    series : data   <-----is the problem?¿?¿        
});
}); ///cierro get
}   ///cierro function
```

Highcharts not draw the 2 lines as hope . Can any enlightened soul altruist the way?. Thank you very much in advance, it would not do without this community. Thank you !

EDIT: i can´t upload a image with table BD on post, sorry! ...i need at least 10 reputation! ...link... 
http://i57.tinypic.com/2efj43n.jpg

EDIT 2:
Thanks to Jerko by response... ...review under for the correct code/response!

Comment: Several things, are you getting any errors? Where are you calling this php file? If you have firebug in firefox, can you see the ajax connection being made? Is the ajax request returning any errors?

Comment: Hi Battle! ...no error returned... The PHP file response Ok... but the  highchart on javascript file not drawing anything... :(

Comment: Can you double check you include ALL the proper JavaScript and CSS files? Also please post a demo link if possible

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: Seems. It may be that the missing comma between the brackets?

Comment: Oki! Battle.. i try... ....i´m super newbie!

Answer (score 2):

try this out

```
$items2  = array();
while ($row_RecordsetTabla2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla2))
{
    $idDispositivo = $row_RecordsetTabla2['idDispositivo']; 

    $query_RecordsetTabla3 = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE idUsuario = (SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE userName = '$sesionUser') AND idDispositivo = '$idDispositivo' AND fecha = '$sesionFechaActualArreglo'";
    $RecordsetTabla3 = mysql_query($query_RecordsetTabla3, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalRows_RecordsetTabla3 = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetTabla3);
    if ($totalRows_RecordsetTabla3 != 0) {  ///para ver si tienen resultados la consulta
    unset($items);      

        while ($row_RecordsetTabla3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla3))
        {
            $fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla3['fecha'];
            $hora = $row_RecordsetTabla3['hora'];
            $estado = $row_RecordsetTabla3['estado']; 
            $arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y-m-d");
            $arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H:i");
            $arregloHora2 = strtotime($arregloHora) * 1000;
            $arr = array($arregloHora2, floatval($estado));
            $items['data'][]  =  $arr;
        }
        $items['name'] = $idDispositivo;

        array_push($items2, $items);

    } //del if
}

echo json_encode($items2);
```

Comment: WAW! Yeess! I can not believe! Jerko save me again! it´s work!

Comment: Fast and effective. My respect and admiration!

Comment: I'm glad I could help again :) don't forget to mark my answer as correct it might help to others too ;)

Comment: Yes! you are great! ...¿who i can mark your answer as correct? ...i can´t vote up ...the web tellme i´m not have a reputation...

Comment: ...i put your profile directly to "My favorites" ...and homepage maybe!jajajaj

Comment: wow! ...i can voteup now! ...i´m 16-5 rank! ...i sure you've done something  for up my poor rank! jajaj .... I owe you many beers!

Comment: To accept answer just click sign on a right side of the voting arrows ;)